# i want to detect face from image in android

Tags: android

I have this code to detect face from an image and draw a red rectangle around it, but I have a run time exception can anyone fix it please i have no idea what to do , i tried a lot of face detection code but also didn't work

```
{
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
   {
 Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
 ImageView myImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgview);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)

{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);




    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inMutable=true;
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                    getApplicationContext().getResources(),
                    R.drawable.test1,
                    options);

            Paint myRectPaint = new Paint();
            myRectPaint.setStrokeWidth(5);
            myRectPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
            myRectPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

            Bitmap tempBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(myBitmap.getWidth(), myBitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
            Canvas tempCanvas = new Canvas(tempBitmap);
            tempCanvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap, 0, 0, null);

            FaceDetector faceDetector = new
                    FaceDetector.Builder(getApplicationContext()).setTrackingEnabled(false)
                    .build();
            if(!faceDetector.isOperational()){
                new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext()).setMessage("Could not set up the face detector!").show();
                return;
            }
            Frame frame = new Frame.Builder().setBitmap(myBitmap).build();
            SparseArray<Face> faces = faceDetector.detect(frame);

            for(int i=0; i<faces.size(); i++) {
                Face thisFace = faces.valueAt(i);
                float x1 = thisFace.getPosition().x;
                float y1 = thisFace.getPosition().y;
                float x2 = x1 + thisFace.getWidth();
                float y2 = y1 + thisFace.getHeight();
                tempCanvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(x1, y1, x2, y2), 2, 2, myRectPaint);
            }
            myImageView.setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),tempBitmap));

        }
    });


}
```

}

```
       here is the exception
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.hadeel.hadd/com.example.hadeel.hadd.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: There should be more in the log cat telling you about the exception that caused this exception. Often reported on Warning level

Comment: You can use this https://github.com/darwinfrancis/viola library to get cropped faces from bitmap image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
>   ImageView myImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgview);`

You shouldn't do initialization of variables which hold references to android widgets like above, because layout of activity is not inflated (method onCreate will run after creation of this object). You should move invocation of `findViewById` right after method `setContentView`

Comment: thank you , it works but if i want to change the image anther exception appear